# Wordpress plugin not passing $_FILES on post save, but is passing $_POST

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am attempting to upload a PDF from a custom Wordpress plugin.  Expected behavior is to create a custom post type `manual`, and upload a PDF from my computer.

The PDF should save in `wp_content/uploads/manuals/`

Currently when I save a `manual` post type, the `$_POST` data is received by `savePost()`, however no `$_FILES` data is sent, so I don't have access to save files.

I have checked php.ini that file upload is allowed, and confirmed that proper permissions are set on the folders for the plugin to upload files.  I've also tested locally and on two different shared hosting providers.  I have also tested that other plugins are able to upload pdfs to this specific directory successfully.  Have also checked that the file size is under the maximum file size allowed.

The only errors I'm receiving are related to `$_FILES` being null.  I can see the file listed in the `$_POST` data however, as `["file"]=> string(9) "dummy.pdf"`

```
//create the manuals custom post type
function create_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'manuals',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Manuals' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Manual' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title','custom_fields'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_post_type' );

//add the manuals box to post page
function manuals_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'manuals_meta_box',
        'Manuals PDF',
        'display_manuals_meta_box',
        'manuals', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'manuals_meta_box' );

//display html on the meta box
function display_manuals_meta_box( $manual ) {
    $saveLocation = ABSPATH.'/wp-content/uploads/manuals';
    if (!file_exists(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/uploads/manuals')) {
        mkdir(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/uploads/manuals', 0777, true);
    }

    //see if this has been uploaded before
    $file = esc_html( get_post_meta( $manual->ID, 'file', true ) );

    ?>
    <p><?php echo $file?$file:'File: Not set';?></p>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'custom-nonce'); ?>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input id="submit" class="submitBtn mfInput" name="submit" type="submit" placeholder="">
    </form>
    <?php
}

//on post save, try to save the pdf selected
function savePost( $manual_id, $manual ) {
    //security checks
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom-nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $manual_id;
    }

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $manual_id;
    }

    if ( $manual->post_type == 'manuals' ){
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $manual_id)) {
        return $manual_id;
      }
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $manual_id)) {
            return $manual_id;
        }
    }

    if ( !function_exists('media_handle_upload') ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }

    moveTheFile($_FILES['file']);
}

//move from tmp to actual file location
function moveTheFile($file){
    $moved = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], ABSPATH . "/wp-content/uploads/manuals/" . $file['name']);
    if( $moved ) {
      echo "Successfully uploaded";
    } else {
      wp_die(var_dump($_FILES).'<br><br>'.var_dump($_POST));
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'savePost', 10, 2 );
```

Errors I receive are:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
Undefined array key "file"
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
move_uploaded_file(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($from) of type string is deprecated
```

Comment: I think you need to use this to upload the file wp_upload_bits i havent played much with uploading stuff but worth the try.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried using wp_upload_bits and wp_handle_upload but regardless of what I use, when I get to the savePost() function, the $_FILES variable is null?  $_POST however is not